# Mongodb query using long milliseconds

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection and I would like to export it every 5 minutes based on timestamp field.

when I query the collection below is the max date:

```
db.testcol.find({},{_id : 0,ts : 1}).sort({ts:-1})      
2017-04-14 23:40:27.690Z

I converted it to milliseconds:  1492213227000

    ex:        max1=db.testcol.find({},{_id : 0,ts : 1}).sort({ts:-1})
               print (new Date(max1).getTime());
```

now if I query the collection there shouldn't be any rows which are greater than  1492213227000

```
ex: db.testcol.find({ts:{$gt:new Date(1492213227000)}},{_id : 0,ts : 1})
```

but still, I am seeing the same value.

```
2017-04-14 23:40:27.690Z
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.690` part of your timestamp. The equivalent milliseconds would be `1492213227690` so that it's preserved.

```
db.testcol.find({ts:{$gt:new Date(1492213227690)}},{_id : 0,ts : 1})
```

Comment: yes, but I want to know why it's missing when I convert it using statement.                   print (new Date(max1).getTime());

Comment: @ashwin `max1` is not a timestamp in your example code, it's a cursor.

Comment: Is there any way I can convert it to time stamp?